# typedef function pointer having templatized parameter

Tags: c++, c++11

I want to create a function pointer for the method signature having Template as a parameter

```
Template<class T>
typedef int (*computeSizeFunc)(T data);
```

I tried this, and this is the error

```
 error: template declaration of 'typedef'
 typedef  int (*computeSizeFunc)(T data).
```

This is the method signature for which I am trying to write Function Pointer

```
template<class T>
int getSize (T data)
```

Answer (score 10):

You should use C++11 [type-alias](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/type_alias) declaration instead:

```
template<class T>
using computeSizeFunc = int (*)(T data);
```

Answer (score 2):

`typedef` doesn't allow `template` usage, you you should use `using`:

```
template<class T>
using computeSizeFunc = int (T data);
```

Answer (score 1):

As a pre-C++11 alternative to the other methods you can use a workaround like this:

```
template< class Arg >
struct computeSizeFunc {
  typedef int (*funcImpl)(Arg data);
};
```